# UILabel not properly centering

Tags: objective-c, ios

When a `UILabel` is pressed, I am making a "highlight" `UILabel` (one with the same frame and position of the pressed `UILabel`) that should flash.

Currently, the highlight label flashes, but is not centering itself correctly. Here is the code:

```
-(void) flashRowViewController:(RowViewController*)rvc
{
    NSLog(@"row center: (%f, %f)", rvc.rowLabel.center.x, rvc.rowLabel.center.y);
    highlight.frame = rvc.rowLabel.frame;
//  highlight.center = rvc.rowLabel.center; // NSlog results are the same with or without this statement
    NSLog(@"highlight center: (%f, %f)", highlight.center.x, highlight.center.y);

    highlight.alpha = 1.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.00 
                     animations:^{
                         highlight.alpha = 0.0;
                     }];
}
```

I am puzzled. Maybe I have just been looking at this too long and need an outside perspective. Here is an example of the NSLog:

> 2012-05-28 10:40:41.603 RREF[89755:f803] row center: (138.000000,
>   40.000000)
>
> 2012-05-28 10:40:41.604 RREF[89755:f803] highlight center:
>   (138.000000, 40.000000)
>
> 2012-05-28 10:40:43.538 RREF[89755:f803] row center: (138.000000,
>   120.000000)
>
> 2012-05-28 10:40:43.538 RREF[89755:f803] highlight center:
>   (138.000000, 120.000000)
>
> 2012-05-28 10:40:45.533 RREF[89755:f803] row center: (138.000000,
>   200.000000)
>
> 2012-05-28 10:40:45.534 RREF[89755:f803] highlight center:
>   (138.000000, 200.000000)

The actual coordinates are current in this output. The highlight label just isn't moving to the right spot! Again, it flashes currently, just no centering.

Comment: Do they both have the same superview?

Comment: Yes, they are both members of the same superview. I also forgot to mention that the highlight label's position is not just offset by a certain amount, it does not move at ALL.

Comment: Are you sure that `highlight` isn't `nil`?

Comment: I am sure because I also tested it by changing the background color after the .center call. And the change reflected in the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `highlightedTextColor` so for instance

```
label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

And then in your touch event:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
         animations:^(void) {
            label.highlighted = YES; 
         }
         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                label.highlighted = NO; 
         }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried iTukker's solution yet but I got another good solution, which is animating the background color using `[label.layer setBackgroundColor:(CGColor)]`

```
-(void) flashRowViewController:(RowViewController*)rvc
{
    [rvc.rowLabel.layer setBackgroundColor:[highlightColor CGColor]];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.00 
                     animations:^{
                         [rvc.rowLabel.layer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
                     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using `NSStringFromCGPoint` function to print out view center.

Second - are you sure you are changing the frame only at this place? The animation takes a second, so if you ovewrite the highlight position somewhere else, it won't be centered even if the log is correct. Did you try to log the position in animation completion callback?

Third - are you sure the two labels are created in the same way? What about text alignment? What about font size? When you say "is not centering itself correctly", what does that mean?

Forth - you can use the animation to change the color/background of the first label, you don't need two labels for it.